# What is the common name of the content injection pattern in CMS

Tags: content-management-system, naming-conventions

What is common name for the patterns in CMS contents? Like:

```
Hello {{FIRSTNAME}}
Your order was sent to: 
{{ADDRESS}}
```

Are these

- variables
- patterns
- blocks
- placeholders
- macros
- or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the system and your environment.

In a programming environment I would name them **variables** and all around is the **template**.

But **placeholder** is also okay, especially if you talk to non-programmers.

HTH.